# Extract a worksheet name from the range selected

Tags: excel, worksheet, inputbox, vba

I have to input the result in the selected cell through InputBox function:

```
Set OutputStrt = Application.InputBox("Select a cell, where the output should be dropped.", "Output start cell", Type:=8)
```

When I ran the code in the different worksheet and want the result in the different worksheet, it drops the result in the worksheet where I initially ran the code.

How do I get the Worksheet name, which I selected through the Application.InputBox ?

For example, when I selected in the Inputbox: Definitions!$F$38 how do I get the name 'Definitions'?

Comment: `OutputStrt.Parent.Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim OutputStrt As Range
    Set OutputStrt = Application.InputBox("Select a cell, where the output should be dropped.", "Output start cell", Type:=8)
    Set Ws = OutputStrt.Worksheet
    MsgBox Ws.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! .Name was what I needed.

Comment: Had the same problem. Thanks for the answer. It seems that if you pick another workbook you don't have to specify it. @Fadi

Answer (score 0):

You can also call it with **Selection** object

```
Dim ws As Workseet
Set ws = Selection.Worksheet
Debug.Print "Sheetname: " & ws.Name
```